# chmod not working on vbox shared folder

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, mount, chmod

The folder `/var/www` was mounted during init, using:

`mount -t vboxsf cuckoo_shared /var/www/ -o uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,dmode=755`

Now, all the files belong to my user `jdrummond` as default. And also have `755` as default mode.

But now every `chmod` that I try to run doesn't seem to work:
[image: chmod try]

My doubts on this are:

**First**: why is my index.php file `777` even when I said it should be `755` on the mount command?

**Second**: why isn't my `chmod` working?

Thanks

---

I've tried to run the `chmod` command with `sudo` but it also didn't work.

Virtualbox 4.1.18:

> Host = Windows 7
>
> Guest = Ubuntu 11.04.

---

**Edit**: Just tried the same in another machine, also with the same specs and:

[image: dafuq]

Weird?

Comment: Which VirtualBox version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the files are stored on an NTFS or FAT filesystem on the Windows host. NTFS and FAT have no concept of *nix executability, and so it is not possible to store this information when you try to `chmod` a file. This is also why *all* files are executable -- in order to be able to execute any files, they all have to be made executable.

Comment: Actually no. Check this weird behavior: http://i.imgur.com/V7xVq.png (Another machine with Guest Ubuntu 11.04, Host Win 7)

Comment: @jlcd What part is weird? That the read permissions aren't removed? The rest is expected.

Comment: I don't get why it accepts `chmod 000` but not `chmod 644`

Answer (score 0):

Since the folder is shared by the host, I suspect that you cannot change the permission from the guest. Do a `chmod` on the host to see if it works.

Comment: Host = windows.

Comment: Also does not work when host is Linux. The file is executable on the host, but not in VirtualBox.